# Problema con Fichero en Java

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un archivo con varios datos de un "Empleado", que son: Id, Nombre... etc.

Necesito pedir por teclado al usuario un **ID** y buscar en el archivo ese **ID** y que me muestre por consola los datos de ese "Empleado".

> El archivo debe de ser un `RandomAccessFile` acabado en `.dat`

Pero el problema es que mi código solo me devuelve el empleado con el **ID** 1. Es decir, me devuelve solo el primer elemento que encuentra, y los demás no.

Si introduzco un numero 2, se queda como bucle infinito. Y no se que esta fallando, **¿alguna idea?**

```
    public static void Consultar(File archivo) throws IOException {

            RandomAccessFile aleatorio = new RandomAccessFile(archivo,"r");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            byte id;
            int departamento;
            double salario;
            String apellido;
            boolean coincide = false;
            int consulta;

        System.out.println("Introduce un ID:");
        consulta = sc.nextInt();

        do {

            try {

                aleatorio.seek(0);

                id = aleatorio.readByte();
                apellido = aleatorio.readUTF();
                departamento = aleatorio.readInt();
                salario = aleatorio.readDouble();

                if(id == consulta) {

                    coincide = true;
                    System.out.println("ID: " + id + " Apellido: " + apellido + " Departamento: " + departamento + " Salario: " + salario);

                }

        }catch(EOFException e) {

            e.getMessage();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.getMessage();
        }

        }while(!coincide & aleatorio.getFilePointer() < aleatorio.length());

        aleatorio.close();  
}
```

Comment: que estructura tienen los datos en tu archivo .dat, podrías poner un ejemplo por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que en este caso lo mejor es abrir el archivo .dat de la forma que indica esta publicación:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258810/how-do-i-read-in-a-line-from-a-dat-file-in-java-that-then-needs-to-be-separated

```
  String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(archivo.toPath()).toArray(new String[0]);
```

De esta forma obtienes un arreglo de las lineas que contiene el archivo, suponiendo que tu archivo tiene esta estructura:

```
1 Elenasys 4231 12.1
2 Gonzalo 5563 22.2 
3 Christoph 4326 33.3
4 Alvaro 7665 44.4
5 Freddy 8564 55.5
```

Puedes obtener el archivo y a su vez generar un array de los valores por linea, obtienes el primer valor del array (`values[0]`) el cual será el `id` y lo comparas con la variable `consulta`, si son iguales procedes a imprimir el resultado:

```
               //Obtiene array de lineas contenidas en archivo.
                String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(archivo.toPath()).toArray(new String[0]);
                //Analiza cada linea y compara si encuentra el id a consultar.
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] values = line.split(" ");
                    id = Byte.parseByte(values[0]);
                    if (id == consulta) {
                        apellido = values[1];
                        departamento = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
                        salario = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);
                        //Imprime valores.
                        System.out.println("ID: " + id + " Apellido: " + apellido + " Departamento: " + departamento + " Salario: " + salario);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Como leer un archivo .dat:

Este sería un  ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
public static void Consultar(File archivo) throws IOException {

        RandomAccessFile aleatorio = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        byte id;
        int departamento = 0;
        double salario = 0;
        String apellido = null;
        boolean coincide = false;
        int consulta;

        System.out.println("Introduce un ID:");
        consulta = sc.nextInt();

        do {

            try {
                //Obtiene array de lineas contenidas en archivo.
                String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(archivo.toPath()).toArray(new String[0]);
                //Analiza cada linea y compara si encuentra el id a consultar.
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] values = line.split(" ");
                    id = Byte.parseByte(values[0]);
                    if (id == consulta) {
                        apellido = values[1];
                        departamento = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
                        salario = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);

                        System.out.println("ID: " + id + " Apellido: " + apellido + " Departamento: " + departamento + " Salario: " + salario);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                coincide = true;//Indica terminar ejecución

            } catch (EOFException e) {

                e.getMessage();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.getMessage();
            }

        } while (!coincide & aleatorio.getFilePointer() < aleatorio.length());

        aleatorio.close();
    }
```